# Trying to use global variables in a T or F game

Tags: python, global

I have no idea how to fix this error so that i can add up points for every game won and to take away rounds.

you pick how many rounds you want to play and as you play each one, 1 gets taken off the 'round' variable until you have 0, which will not let you play anymore and take you straight to the score function.

the points are to keep track of what games you/the bot have won in order to see who has won in the end (after all rounds completed)

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 99, in <module>
  File "python", line 13, in login
  File "python", line 30, in start
  File "python", line 33, in rcheck
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'round' referenced before assignment
```

here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
import random

print("Rock, Paper, Scissors. By Leona Bryant")
print("")

def login():
  username=input("Username: ")
  password=input("Password: ")
  if (username == "shinleona" ) and (password == "hacker101"):
    print ("")
    print ("Welcome back Leona!")
    start()
  else:
    print("")
    print ("Invalid credidentals, try again.")
    login()


def start():
  print("")
  round=int(input("How many rounds would you like to play? Please pick from 3-10"))
  if (round <3 ):
    print("Invalid number, try again.")
    start()
  else:
    print("")
    print("Loading..")
    sleep(3)
    rcheck()

def rcheck():
  if (round <=0 ):
    print("End of game!")
    print("Calculating scores...")
    score()
  else:
    round-=1
    game()


def game():
  print("")
  rps=("rock" , "paper" , "scissors")
  bot = random.choice(rps)
  user=input("Rock..Paper..Scissors..SHOOT!").lower()
  print("The bot chose" , bot )

  if (bot == user):
    print ("This round was a draw, you both gain 1 point!")
    point+=1 
    bpoint+=1
    rcheck()

  elif ( (bot == "paper") and (user == "rock") ) or ( (bot == "scissors") and (user == "paper") ) or ( (bot == "rock") and (user == "scissors") ):
    print ("You Lose this round, Bot gains 1 point!")
    bpoint+=1 
    rcheck()

  else:
    print("You won this round, User gains 1 point!")
    point+=1
    rcheck()




def score():
  if (point > bpoint):
    print("Congratulations, you won the game with" , point , "points")
    again()

  else:
    print("Sorry, you lost the game. The bot won with" , bpoint , "points")
    again()


def again():
  play=input("Play again?").lower
  if (play[0] == "y"):
    start()

  elif (play[0] == "n"):
    print("Thanks for playing!")
    exit()

  else:
    print ("Invalid answer, try again.")
    again()

round = 0 
point = 0 
bpoint = 0 

global round
global bpoint
global point 

login()
```

Comment: Variable assignments (including function assignments) are made in order. Move the global definitions to the top and it should work. Also this programming is begging to use [object oriented principles](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm), maybe consider restructuring so that `round`, `point` and `bpoint` are class properties rather than global values.

Comment: Don't use global variables. Function parameter and return values are made for this.

Comment: Global variables should never be something you reach for unless **absolutely** necessary. In this case,  I can't see any advantage to using them. Explicitly pass arguments to functions, and explicitly return values from them. Once you write programs that are more than small tests, global mutable variables start causing all kinds of problems.

Comment: If you want to avoid passing and returning variables, at least store the state in an enclosed namespace (a class/object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global` is used within a function to indicate that a value it is modifying is from an external (module) scope. It is useless in module-level code. You should delete the lines

```
global round
global bpoint
global point
```

In MATLAB, they would make the names globally available. In Python they do nothing since the variables are already defined in the module scope.

Add the line `global round` to `rcheck` (and corresponding lines to functions that use global variables). This tells python that the name `round` in the function is actually a global variable, i.e. defined in the module. Without the `global` statement, the function attempts to do `round = round + 1`, but the `round` on the right hand side is not defined in the function's scope.

And of course, do not use globals if you can avoid it. Write a class that has all the necessary state and functionality, or at least pass the values to your functions and accept updates via return values.

Answer (score 0):

You're not bringing in the global variable into the method add the following to the top of your rcheck() method:

```
global round
```

This should allow you to use this global variable.